# Object Oriented Tic Tac Toe Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe

I've been learning to code in my spare time for a couple of years. I have covered object oriented stuff before and can usually understand other people's object oriented code. This is the first time I've written an object oriented program from scratch.

It has all the functionality that I want and (hopefully) no mistakes - I have stress tested it.

However, I still feel the code is a bit dirty so I'd like some suggested improvements. Some areas that I feel I've gone wrong:

1, I have put too much functionality into the board class and not enough into the player class. Is this an issue?

2, It was relatively streamlined to begin with but then I started adding stuff to "make it look cool" such as a coin toss to decide who goes first and drawing the winning line on the board/displaying a victory message. This is all great but my code seems to have gotten less clean as the game loop function is a bit messy - any recommendations for how to repackage it?

3, Any other comments? StackExchange can be a very brutal place; please be gentle in your critique......

4, Any recommendations for a next project that would be slightly harder but still manageable for someone of my level.

My code:

```
import random
import pygame
import itertools

# Initailize PyGame object
pygame.init()
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 600
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600
BLOCK_SIZE = 200

# Defining colors (rgb values)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
pink = (255, 20, 147)
cyan = (0, 255, 255)
gray = (128, 128, 128)

# Draw black rectangle to cover square numbers once played
def draw_rect(x, y, color = black, size=30, width = 0):
    pygame.draw.polygon(gameDisplay, color, [(x-size, y-size), (x-size, y+size), (x+size, y+size), (x+size, y-size)], width)
def draw_wide_rect(x, y, color = black, size=30, width = 0):
    pygame.draw.polygon(gameDisplay, color, [(x-3*size, y-2*size), (x-3*size, y+2*size), (x+3*size, y+2*size), (x+3*size, y-2*size)], width)
# How to draw naughts and crosses
def draw_naught(x, y, color, radius = 40, thickness = 20):
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color, (x,y), radius, thickness)

def draw_cross(x, y, color, closed = False, thickness = 20):
    pygame.draw.lines(gameDisplay, color, closed, [(x-30, y-30), (x+30, y+30)], thickness)
    pygame.draw.lines(gameDisplay, color, closed , [(x+30, y-30), (x-30, y+30)], thickness)

largefont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 80)
player_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
def display_text(text, x, y, color):
    text = largefont.render("{}".format(str(text)), True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [x, y])

# Set up the display
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT + 100))
pygame.display.set_caption("Naughts and Crosses")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Draw the background grid           
def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (x,0),(x,w), 10)
    pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (0,y),(w,y), 10)
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (x,0),(x,w), 10)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (0,y),(w,y), 10)




class Board:
    def __init__(self, current_player, next_player, naught_list = [], cross_list = []):
        self.naught_list = naught_list
        self.cross_list = cross_list
        self.empty_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        self.current_player = current_player
        self.next_player = next_player
        self.naught_trebles = []
        self.naught_treble_sums = []
        self.cross_trebles = []
        self.cross_treble_sums = []
        self.magic_dic = {1: 6,
                          2: 1,
                          3: 8,
                          4: 7,
                          5: 5,
                          6: 3,
                          7: 2,
                          8: 9,
                          9: 4}


    def create_board(self):
        gameDisplay.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        drawGrid(DISPLAY_WIDTH, int(DISPLAY_WIDTH / BLOCK_SIZE), gameDisplay)

        for i in range(9):
            display_text(str(i+1), ((i)%3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2.5, (i//3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2.5, white)


    def cover_text(self, square_num):
        x = int((square_num%3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
        y = int((square_num//3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)


    def play_move(self, marker, square_num, player):
        if player.marker == 'naughts':
            if int(square_num) in self.empty_list:
                idx = square_num - 1 # user numbering starts at 1 but Python starts at 0
                x = int((idx%3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
                y = int((idx//3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
                draw_rect(x, y)
                draw_naught(x, y, player.color)

                self.empty_list.remove(square_num)
                self.naught_list.append(square_num)
                tmp = player
                self.current_player = self.next_player
                self.next_player = tmp
            else:
                print("Invalid move - square already taken. Pick again please:")
                return 0 
        elif player.marker == 'crosses':
            if int(square_num) in self.empty_list:
                idx = square_num - 1 # user numbering starts at 1 but Python starts at 0
                x = int((idx%3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
                y = int((idx//3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
                draw_rect(x, y)
                draw_cross(x, y, player.color)

                self.empty_list.remove(square_num)
                self.cross_list.append(square_num)
                tmp = player
                self.current_player = self.next_player
                self.next_player = tmp
            else:
                print("Invalid move - square already taken. Pick again please:")
                return 0 
        else:
            print("Invalid marker for this player.")



    def victory_line(self, winning_list, color, closed = False, thickness = 20):
        # get the square numbers of the winning line. These will be in terms of magic square from magic_dic
        magic_list_0 = winning_list[0]
        magic_list_1 = winning_list[1]
        magic_list_2 = winning_list[2]

        # convert them back to the square numbers we see on the screen
        for key in self.magic_dic:
            if magic_list_0 == self.magic_dic[key]:
                list_0 = key

        for key in self.magic_dic:
            if magic_list_1 == self.magic_dic[key]:
                list_1 = key

        for key in self.magic_dic:
            if magic_list_2 == self.magic_dic[key]:
                list_2 = key

        non_magic_list = [list_0, list_1, list_2]

        # subtract 1 as pygame numbers squares from 0 and we number from 1
        left_idx = min(non_magic_list) - 1
        right_idx = max(non_magic_list) -1 

        # get coords
        left_x = int((left_idx%3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
        left_y = int((left_idx//3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
        right_x = int((right_idx%3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)
        right_y = int((right_idx//3)*BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE/2)

        # draw a line to show winning combination
        pygame.draw.lines(gameDisplay, color, closed , [(left_x, left_y), (right_x, right_y)], thickness)

    def magic_square_winner_check(self, player):
        # magic square has every row, column and diagonal sum to 15 meaning we can just check if any triple of used squares sums to 15
        # this won't be computationally challenging due to small board size. at most 5C3 = 10 combinations (no player can occupy more than 5 squares) 
        # current numbering is not magic so we must first use a dictionary to magic-ify the board


        if player.marker == 'naughts':
            updated_naught_list = [self.magic_dic[x] for x in self.naught_list]
            self.naught_trebles = list(itertools.combinations(updated_naught_list, 3))
            self.naught_treble_sums = [sum(x) for x in self.naught_trebles]
            if 15 in self.naught_treble_sums:
                print("Victory")
                return 1

        elif player.marker == 'crosses':
            updated_cross_list = [self.magic_dic[x] for x in self.cross_list]
            self.cross_trebles = list(itertools.combinations(updated_cross_list, 3))
            self.cross_treble_sums = [sum(x) for x in self.cross_trebles]
            if 15 in self.cross_treble_sums:
                print("Victory")
                return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def victory_message(self, msg, x = DISPLAY_WIDTH//5, y=DISPLAY_HEIGHT+20, color = cyan):
        text = largefont.render("{} wins!".format(str(msg)), True, color)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [x, y])

    def draw_message(self, x = DISPLAY_WIDTH//6, y=DISPLAY_HEIGHT+20, color = cyan):
        text = largefont.render("A boring draw...", True, color)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [x, y])

    def player1_text(self, color, x = 10, y=DISPLAY_HEIGHT+30):
        text = player_font.render("Player 1", True, color)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [x, y])

    def player2_text(self, color, x = DISPLAY_WIDTH - 160, y= DISPLAY_HEIGHT+30):
        text = player_font.render("Player 2", True, color)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [x, y])

class Player:
    def __init__(self, marker, coin_toss_victor, color, name):
        self.marker = marker # naughts or crosses
        self.coin_toss_victor = coin_toss_victor #boolean indication of who starts
        self.color = color
        self.name = name
        pass

    def request_move(self, board):
        move = input("Choose a square: ")
        tmp = move
        while move.isnumeric() == False:
            move = input("{} is not an int! Choose again: ".format(tmp))
        move = int(move)
        # check valid
        while move not in range(1,10):
            tmp = move
            move = int(input("{} is not a valid square. Please choose again: ".format(tmp)))
        while move not in board.empty_list:
            #board.square_taken_message()
            tmp = move            
            move = int(input("Square {} is already taken. Please choose again: ".format(tmp)))

        return move


"""<<<GAME LOOP>>>"""

def game_loop():
    # display screen asking for coin fkip guess
    gameDisplay.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50)
    textsurface = myfont.render("Heads or Tails?", True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(textsurface, [60, 10])
    pygame.display.update()

    # receive coin guess
    coin = ["H", "T"]
    coin_toss = input("We will decide who goes first with a coin flip. Player 1 pease enter H or T: ")
    if coin_toss not in coin:
        coin_toss = input("Not a valid input. Please enter H or T: ")

    # dictionary for translating input to display words
    coin_dic = {"H" : "Heads", "T": "Tails"}

    # random toss. display the guess now. display the outcome after images
    random_toss = random.choice(coin)
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50)
    textsurface2 = myfont.render("Your choice: {}".format(coin_dic[coin_toss]), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(textsurface2, [60, DISPLAY_HEIGHT - 140])


    # load two images of coin
    coin_a = pygame.image.load('coin_a.png')
    coin_b = pygame.image.load('coin_b.png')
    tosser = 0

    textsurface3 = myfont.render("Result: {}".format(coin_dic[random_toss]), True, white)
    if coin_toss == random_toss:
        textsurface4 = myfont.render("Win! You go first!", True, white)
    else:
        textsurface4 = myfont.render("Lose! You go second!", True, white)
    # change image 20 times for nice effect. display outcome of coin flip after 10 times.
    while tosser < 21:
        print(20 - tosser)
        gameDisplay.blit(coin_a, (60,DISPLAY_HEIGHT//3))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(100)
        gameDisplay.blit(coin_b, (60, DISPLAY_HEIGHT//3))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(100)
        tosser += 1

        if tosser > 10:
            gameDisplay.blit(textsurface3, [60, DISPLAY_HEIGHT - 70])
            gameDisplay.blit(textsurface4, [60, DISPLAY_HEIGHT])
            pygame.display.update()

    # short pause for user to read result before switching screen to tic-tac-toe
    pygame.time.wait(500)

    # instantiate the player objects according to the result of the coin toss
    while coin_toss not in coin:
        coin_toss = input("You didn't enter a valid input! Try again please: ")
    if coin_toss == random_toss:
        print("Coin toss result was {}".format(random_toss))
        print("Player 1 to go first!")
        p1 = Player('naughts', True, pink, 'Player 1')
        p2 = Player('crosses', False, green, 'Player 2')
        current_player = p1
        next_player = p2
    else:
        print("Coin toss result was {}".format(random_toss))
        print("Player 2 to go first!") 
        p1 = Player('naughts', False, pink, 'Player 1')
        p2 = Player('crosses', True, green, 'Player 2')
        current_player = p2
        next_player = p1

    # instantiate the board and display it
    b = Board(current_player, next_player)
    b.create_board()

    # display current player
    if current_player == p1:
        b.player1_text(white)
        b.player2_text(gray)
    elif current_player == p2:
        b.player1_text(gray)
        b.player2_text(white)
    pygame.display.update()

    # begin while loop - initialise all variables here so they're reset if we restart the game
    play_again = True
    end = False
    b.empty_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    b.naught_list = []
    b.naught_trebles = []
    b.naught_treble_sums = []
    b.cross_list = []
    b.cross_trebles = []
    b.cross_treble_sums = []
    while play_again:

        # display current player
        if current_player == p1:
            b.player1_text(white)
            b.player2_text(gray)
            pygame.display.update()
        elif current_player == p2:
            b.player1_text(gray)
            b.player2_text(white)
            pygame.display.update()

        # allow window to be quit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play_again = False

        # print useful stuff to terminal
        print("-----Empty Squares-----")
        print(b.empty_list)
        print("-----Naughts-----")
        print(b.naught_list)
        print(b.naught_trebles)
        print(b.naught_treble_sums)
        print("-----Crosses-----")
        print(b.cross_list)
        print(b.cross_trebles)
        print(b.cross_treble_sums)

        # request player move and display it
        move = current_player.request_move(b)
        b.play_move(current_player.marker, move, current_player)

        # display current player
        if current_player == p1:
            b.player1_text(white)
            b.player2_text(gray)
            pygame.display.update()
        elif current_player == p2:
            b.player1_text(gray)
            b.player2_text(white)
            pygame.display.update()

        # check if current player has won and then switch player
        if current_player == p1 and end == False:
            if b.magic_square_winner_check(p1) == 1:
                draw_wide_rect(70, DISPLAY_HEIGHT+70)
                draw_wide_rect(DISPLAY_WIDTH - 80, DISPLAY_HEIGHT+70)
                b.victory_message(current_player.name)
                winning_idx = b.naught_treble_sums.index(15)
                winning_tuple = b.naught_trebles[winning_idx]
                winning_list = [x for x in winning_tuple]
                print(winning_list)
                b.victory_line(winning_list, p1.color)
                pygame.display.update()
                end = True
            else:
                current_player = p2

        elif current_player == p2 and end == False:
            if b.magic_square_winner_check(p2) == 1:
                draw_wide_rect(70, DISPLAY_HEIGHT+70)
                draw_wide_rect(DISPLAY_WIDTH - 80, DISPLAY_HEIGHT+70)
                b.victory_message(current_player.name)
                winning_idx = b.cross_treble_sums.index(15)
                winning_tuple = b.cross_trebles[winning_idx]
                winning_list = [x for x in winning_tuple]
                b.victory_line(winning_list, p2.color)
                pygame.display.update()
                end = True
            else:
                current_player = p1

        # check if game is a draw
        if len(b.empty_list) == 0 and end == False:
            b.draw_message()
            pygame.display.update()
            end = True

        # if game reaches a terminal state, return 1 (used as code in main loop to ask about restart)
        if end:
            return 1
        pygame.display.update()


def main():
    end_msg = game_loop()
    while end_msg == True:
        play_again = int(input("Play again? 1 = Yes, 0 = No : "))
        if play_again == 1:
            game_loop()
        if play_again == 0:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```